# Unable to browse virtual host with WAMP

Tags: apache, wamp

I am working on a site that will eventually be hosted on a Linux box. I have decided to use WAMP as my development server so that I can be sure all my Angular.js routing, etc. works properly.

I have WAMP up and running (nice green tray icon).The vhosts module is selected. I have added the following to httpd-vhosts.conf:

```
# mergable.local
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin mike@mahony.us
    DocumentRoot "D:/Main/source/mergable"
    ServerName mergable.local
    ServerAlias www.mergable.local
    ErrorLog "logs/mergable.local-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/mergable.local-access.log" common
    <Directory "/">
        Deny from all
        Allow from 127.0.0.1
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I also added the following to my hosts file:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.0.1       mergable.local
127.0.0.1   www.mergable.local
```

When I browse to `http://www.mergable.local` I get the WAMP configuration page. Any ideas on what I did wrong?

Comment: This line `<Directory "/">` should be `<Directory "D:/Main/source/mergable">` or you are giving access to the root of `D:` to anyone that hacks your site.

Comment: And if you are using Apache 2.4.? `Deny from all Allow from 127.0.0.1` should be `Require local`

Comment: This line in the `hosts` file is also not needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your `apache\conf\httpd.conf` file for

```
#LoadModule vhost_alias_module modules/mod_vhost_alias.so
```

and for

```
# Virtual hosts
#Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

If you have the `#` before the `LoadModule` and `Include` remove it so the virtual hosts config file will run.

Comment: OK, so now I get a different error. It now says "Forbidden

You don't have permission to access /index.html on this server."

I am betting this has something to do with the empty .htaccess file in that website folder? What SHOULD be in the .htaccess file anyway?

Comment: Do you have the file index.html in there, "D:/Main/source/mergable" ?

Comment: Yes the index.html file is in d:/Main/source/mergable

Comment: I had to change the DIRECTORY portion of the httpd-vhosts.conf file to:

`<Directory "/">`
  `Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI`
  `AllowOverride All`
  `Require all granted`
  `Deny from all`
  `Allow from 127.0.0.1`
 `</Directory>`

Comment: .htaccess is used for configuration directives, more about it https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/the-ultimate-guide-to-htaccess-files--net-4757

Comment: `mod_vhost_alias` is not actually required to run simple virtual hosts